# Expression selection return the expression word not the whole row

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I want to ignore the selection of a certain dimension in one expression, but still want that the table to be filtered for that dimension.
Following example

```
ID  Project Project Lead
1   Dog      Josh; Marc
2   Cat      Sophie; Julian
```

So when I filter for Josh, the table looks like that

```
ID  Project Project Lead
1   Dog      Josh
```

But I want it to look like that:

```
ID  Project Project Lead
1   Dog      Josh; Marc
```

ID and Project are dimensions. Project Lead is a expression with Concat(Distinct ProjectLead, '; ')
When I use Set Expression and filter for Josh in ProjectLead, the whole table will not filter anymore. I used Concat({< ProjectLead = >} (Distinct ProjectLead, '; ') . This is the result:

```
ID  Project Project Lead
1   Dog     Josh; Marc
2   Cat     Sophie; Julia
```

Anyone got an idea, how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since your set analysis is ignoring the selection, it is effectively ignoring the filter since the expression produces a result. You can achieve what you want by using an `If` to check if there are valid results taking the selections into account:

```
If(Count(ProjectLead) > 0, Concat({<ProjectLead = >} (Distinct ProjectLead, '; '), )
```

This should preserve your filter.